# To blush To the Toes of Shoes

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when somebody says:" I blush to the toes of my shoes to admit "?

Comment: I've answered, but some context could be helpful, to be honest. Where did you hear this, what was the situation?

Comment: @catija: Thank you so much, I got it, You're right.it's true.

Comment: There's an expression, "to blush to the tips of one's toes," but I've never heard "the toes of my shoes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blushing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blushing) is a physical response often tied to embarrassment.

> Blushing is the reddening of a person's face due to psychological reasons. It is normally involuntary and triggered by emotional stress, such as that associated with embarrassment, anger, or romantic stimulation.

As you can see, it's generally considered to be limited to the face.

If someone "blushes to the toes of [their] shoes" that implies that they find the admission they're about to make so embarrassing, their entire body (probably figuratively) turns red.

Answer (score 3):

Catija provides the correct answer to the OP's question. I just wanted to add that the phrase does go back at least 75 years in roughly the form that the OP describes. From [*The Spectator*](https://books.google.com/books?id=j_YhAQAAMAAJ&q=%22blush+to+the+toes%22&dq=%22blush+to+the+toes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIr4GIqJSMxwIVBlKSCh1cHgLF), volume 165 (1940) [combined snippets]:

> I was out of town when the thing started. As it happened, I did have the opportunity of expressing my opinion, and took it; but it was only a personal opinion—I had no means then of testing the reactions of the people. On the Monday I was in London and made enquiries of a friend, who said that "a lot of poeple were very angry about it." The first advertisements had then appeared; another friend, whom I met on the Tuesday, had little to say about the Silence Campaign, though we agreed that the vagueness of  the instructions  about behaviour in case of air-raid or invasion was only thrown into relief by the intolerable archness of the phrasing employed. We refused to say to ourselves: "This is where I keep perfectly calm and cool"—language like that, we said, made us **blush to the toes of our boots**. Apart from these encounters, I discussed the matter with nobody.

An example using shoes instead of boots appears in Joe Penhall, [*Blue/Orange*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4iCBtRc81H8C&pg=PA76&dq=%22blush+to+the+toes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIr4GIqJSMxwIVBlKSCh1cHgLF#v=onepage&q=%22blush%20to%20the%20toes%22&f=false) (2000):

> **Robert** ... OK, this is very delicate. It's not something we know an awful lot about. But it's my specific field of research, I'm writing a book on it as a matter of fact.
>
> **Christopher** You're writing a book? Really? You're really writing a book?
>
> **Robert** Well ... I **blush to the toes of my shoes** to admit but...
>
> **Christopher** What's it about?

An allied, but much more common and considerably older expression is "blush to the roots of [one's] hair," again using exaggeration to convey a sense of deep embarrassment. The earliest Google Books match for this phrase is from "[Ranger's Answer to Paddy Whack](https://books.google.com/books?id=82w6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA259&dq=%22blush+to+the+roots+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwATgKahUKEwju7Ne7rIzHAhXYEpIKHVhfCvM#v=onepage&q=%22blush%20to%20the%20roots%20of%22&f=false)," in *The New Sports Magazine* (April 1838):

> I shall now give an instance or two of another class of malcontents—I mean the claimants for loss and damage to hen-roosts and fowl-houses, which (I **blush to the roots of my hair** while I write the sentence,) is not confined to the farmers' wives.